# Inconsistent accessibility error in xna

Tags: xna

Hey all, you may remember me asking a question regarding a snake game I was creating about two weeks ago.

Well I'm quite far now into making the game (thanks to a brilliant tutorial I found). But I've come across the error described named above.

So heres my problem;

I have a SnakeFood class that has a method called "Reposition". In the game1 class I have a method called "UpdateInGame" which calls the reposition method to load an orange that spawns in a random place every second.

My latest piece of code changed the reposition method to allow the snake I have on the screen to not be overlapped by the orange that randomly spawns.

Now I get the error (in full):

Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'TheMathsSnakeGame.Snake' is less accessible than method 'TheMathsSnakeGame.SnakeFood.Reposition(TheMathsSnakeGame.Snake)'   C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TheMathsSnakeGame\TheMathsSnakeGame\SnakeFood.cs 33  21  TheMathsSnakeGame

I understand what the errors trying to tell me but having changed the accessiblity of the methods, I still can't get it to work.

Sorry about the longwinded question.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: Code I'm using

```
 (Game1 Class)
private void UpdateInGame(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //Calls the oranges "reposition" method every second
        if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds % 1000 == 0)
            orange.Reposition(sidney);
        sidney.Update(gameTime);
    }

(SnakeFood Class)
 public void Reposition(Snake snake)
    {
        do
        {
            position = new Point(rand.Next(Grid.maxHeight),     rand.Next(Grid.maxWidth));
        } while (snake.IsBodyOnPoint(position));
    }
```

Comment: Some example code will help.

Comment: Theres too much code to copy and paste, would you like me to copy and paste the code spoken of above?

Comment: You don't have to copy and paste everything, just the appropriate code that you're having issues with.

Answer (score 5):

The accessibility levels of C# are `public` > `protected` > `internal` > `protected internal` > `private`. Your class' accessibility must by >= to the accessibility of the methods it contains.

Comment: +1. meaning you have a variable: TheMathsSnakeGame.Snake. This is an instantiation of some class. Make that class a public class so it's ok to pass any instantiated objects of that class as params to other class' public methods (i.e. .Reposition())

Comment: Thank you Steve, I've just made the Snake class public instead of its default (which is private?) and it has worked :D

Thank you! :)

Comment: internal is the default access modifier, when none is specified (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)